# Resize MathJax text in a plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, mathjax

I'm working on plots that will be printed, and I need to rescale the texts for readability.

As it's some scientific stuff, the plots include MathJax labels, but I can't find how to rescale them.

Here is a working code sample showing my prpblem :

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Dummy data
y1 = [5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2]
y2 = [3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2]
x= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Fig trace, legend placement
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, name='$P_{1}$'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, name='P-2'))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation='h',yanchor='bottom',y=1.01,xanchor='center',x=0.5))

### PROBLEMATIC SAMPLE ###
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(      
    font=dict(                      
        size=32                     
    )                               
))                                  


# Image export
fig.write_image('test.png', width=100, height=50, scale=1)
```

And here is the `test.png` result :

[image: Result with wrong sizes]

I've searched plotly documentation and I couldn't find the solution. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Each legend element can be realized by specifying the Mathjax font size; a reference to Latex can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/), and the information on which this answer is based can be found [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/latex-and-plotly-font-sizes-on-x-and-y-labels/49380).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Dummy data
y1 = [5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2]
y2 = [3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2]
x= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Fig trace, legend placement
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, name='$\Large{P_{1}}$'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, name='$\Large{P-2}$'))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation='h', yanchor='bottom', y=1.01, xanchor='center', x=0.5, entrywidth=50))

### PROBLEMATIC SAMPLE ###
# fig.update_layout(legend=dict(      
#     font=dict(                      
#         size=32                     
#     )                               
# ))

fig.show()
```

[image]